# How to disable TRACE method in Apigee server

Tags: trace, apigee

Is there any way to disable TRACE HTTP method in Apigee server?

Answer (score 1):

In your proxy.xml you can set a configuration like below:

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
        <BasePath>/v1/abc</BasePath>
        <Properties>
            <Property name="allow.http.method.TRACE">false</Property>
        </Properties>
        <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
```